# WordPress posts randomly adding spans with fonts on Publish

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, post, fonts, microsoft-edge

I am the sole Web Developer at a News company (which is why I must frequent here every now and then). Long story short, one of the websites has been having an issue where when a post is published there will be code that adds formatting and fonts that nobody seems to know where it comes from:

```
<span style="display: inline !important; float: none; background-color: transparent; color: #333333; cursor: text; font-family: Georgia,'Times New Roman','Bitstream Charter',Times,serif; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; white-space: normal; word-spacing: 0px;">
```

They have said that it typically happens when:

1. Someone writes a post and saves as Draft.
2. Other Editor makes suggestions and saves as Draft.
3. Writer implements suggestions, saves as draft, and sends back to Editor.
4. Editor Publishes post (and then strange formatting appears).

They say it happens randomly...I myself have witnessed this process myself, and did not see strange formatting...it only seems to happen when I'm not looking over their shoulder.

Things that I've told them to do / not to do...that they say they are following:

1. One of the Editors said that she was working in Edge while the rest are in chrome...She switched to Chrome and said that it was still happening.
2. When copy and pasting from Word document make sure clear formatting.
3. I thought it might be from a browser extension called Grammarly that they use...but they say that it was happening before that was installed.

Anyone have any idea what this problem could be? All I can find online is people that have this happen through copy / pasting without clearing formmating or possibly because of extensions. What else could the problem be? Why would it be happening so inconsistently?

Answer (score 0):

Try copy it from note pad not in word document file.

Comment: Right but they say that it doesn't happen when they copy and paste from Word...they've been clearing the formatting. They say that it only seems to happen when they pass the post back and forth a couple of times, and then only see the weird span / fonts after they have published the post.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is reproducible using multi browser, then it is possible that maybe the issue is with your code.

It is possible that the style and formatting get modified by your code when the user moves forth and back post back.

You need to make a test with your code and try to produce the issue on your development environment.

If you can successfully produce the issue, then you can find what causes this behavior and modify your code to remove this behavior, or don't allow the user from moving forward and back postback may solve your issue.

Also, try to flush the inputted data once get entered in the database.

So, if the user moves forward and back, then it does not cause this issue.

Comment: The problem is I'm using the same theme / code on several websites in the company and this is the only one that has this issue. Also, again, I've never been able to reproduce the issue myself and it never happens when they do it in front of me.

Comment: Try to work with those employees and try to know whether there is any certain way to produce the issue or if possible for you then try to check the issue onsite  when they meet with it next time.